# mousemove event automatically triggered

Tags: javascript, mousemove, eventtrigger

I found this morning something really strange, and to be honest I don't have any idea about where I can start searching for this problem.

I've created a routine for my code to disconnect a user after one hour of inactivity.

It's simple, I've put a listener on mousemove event with a timeout which will call a function to disconnect a user after 3600000ms.
Each time the mousemove event is triggered, the timeout is reset because it's an activity.

But, I found this morning (working on chrome Version 54.0.2840.99 m) that every 3 minutes an "automatic" mousemove event is triggered.

I've made a test this morning, change timeout value to 10 minutes, and go walk outside waiting for the timeout. When I came back 15 minutes later there were some mousemove event which where triggered every 3 minutes, and the disconnection function was not called because of the reset of the timeout.

Try to search on the web about it, and I don't find anything about it. I'm using Polymer. 
I don't search for the moment if Polymer sends an automatic event every minutes, i'll do it. 
Tried on a colleague computer, don't have any automatic event triggered.

Does anyone have an idea where I can search?

Thanks a lot

Edit :

```
    // automatically called by polymer
    ready: function ready() {
            this._disconnectTimeout = setTimeout(this._disconnect.bind(this), 3600000);
    },

    _onGlobalMouseMove : function _onGlobalMouseMove () {
            clearTimeout(this._disconnectTimeout);
            // amIConnected is a variabled setted to true when the user log in
            if (this.amIConnected == true) {
                    // console.log("move, setTimeout")
                    // console.log(new Date())
                    this._disconnectTimeout = setTimeout(this._disconnect.bind(this), 3600000);
            }
    },

    _disconnect : function _disconnect () {
            clearTimeout(this._disconnectTimeout);
            console.log("disconnect")
            // function in a singleton to disconnect
            session.getInstance().disconnect();
    },
```

Log with a disconnected mouse :

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:16:19 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:16:19 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid) ==> last user movement

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:18:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid) ==> first automatic mouvemove, every 3 minutes

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:18:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:18:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:18:01 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:21:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:21:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:21:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:21:01 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:24:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:24:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:24:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:24:01 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:27:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:27:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:27:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:27:01 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:30:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:30:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:30:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)

move
Thu Nov 24 2016 09:30:01 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)

Comment: please share your code

Comment: if you are using an optical mouse some ghost mouse movements can occur. try disabling your own mouse to check. Also add distance check to your event. if mouse moved for less than, say, 5 pixels, then do not register it as a mouse movement

Comment: I'll try to disconnect my mouse, and i'll add a distance check, thanks @AlexBykov